# MySQL - 0 or 1 character select query

Tags: mysql, regex, select, option-type

is there any way in MySQL to select terms that contain **OPTIONALLY** (0 or 1) a character without using REGEX ?
For instance I want the SQL query to match at the same time xxx_yyy and xxxyyy.
Hope that's clear.

Comment: Is the character always in the same place?

Comment: No the character's place might change. Another way to put is: It's like I want to do xx%xxx, but the % should match up to ONE character.

Comment: Marcus, How would you do it using OR or IN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> WHERE foo = 'xxxxx' OR foo LIKE 'xx_xxx'

In a `LIKE`, the underscore matches exactly one character.

But really, why is `REGEXP` undesirable? Isn't this better?

> WHERE foo RLIKE 'xx.?xxx'

Comment: REGEX is undesirable because user input is highly "unstable. The presence of diacritics in the Arabic language make working with REGEX much more complicated. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/char.html